# Is it possible to escape }} within a replace filter in Liquid?

Tags: filter, replace, escaping, liquid

i'm fairly new to learning Liquid and have not been able to find any documentation how to do to the below without throwing an error.

```
| replace: "]]", "}}"
```

Is there a way to escape the `}}` in this string as I'm sure this is the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `{%- raw -%} {%- endraw -%}` tag to use raw liquid curly braces without considering it as liquid.

and you need to assign it to a variable using `{%- capture name_of_variable -%} {%- endcapture -%}`

and then replace the "]]" with the captured_variable

```
{%- capture my_captured_sign -%}

{%- raw -%}}}{%- endraw -%}

{%- endcapture -%}

<h1>{{'hello]]world' | replace: "]]", my_captured_sign }}</h1>
```

take note: use the sign `-` with the tags, so it should be so you don't include white spaces.

take note: `my_captured_sign` will be added without the `""`